# Access isolate scopes for multiple directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a reusable progress bar directive with isolate scope. This directive will have the public functions to start, stop and reset the progress bar. This directive will be used within `ng-repeat`

Here is the definition of directive:

```
chatApp.directive('jsProgress', function() {

    var Stopwatch = function(options, updateCallback) {

         // var timer       = createTimer(),
           var   offset, clock, interval;

          // default options
          options = options || {};
          options.delay = options.delay || 1;


          // initialize
          reset();

          function start() {
            if (!interval) {
              offset   = Date.now();
              interval = setInterval(update, options.delay);
            }
          }

          function stop() {
            if (interval) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              interval = null;
            }
          }

          function reset() {
            clock = 0;
           // render(0);
          }

          function update() {
            clock += delta();
           // render();
            updateCallback();
          }

          function delta() {
            var now = Date.now(),
                d   = now - offset;

            offset = now;
            return d;
          }

          // public API
          this.start  = start;
          this.stop   = stop;
          this.reset  = reset;
          this.update = update;
        };



    return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        replace : true,
        scope: { api: '=', key: '@'},
        template: '<div class="dot" ng-attr-id="dots"><ul id="{{key}}" data-currentState="2"><li class="dot-red"></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul></div>',
        link : function($scope, elem, attr) {

            var timer = new Stopwatch( {delay: 5000}, updateCallback);
            timer.start();
            function updateCallback()
            {
                var currentCount;
                currentCount = $(elem).find('#' + $scope.key).attr('data-currentState');
                currentCount++;
                $(elem).find('#' + $scope.key).attr('data-currentState',currentCount);
                $(elem).find('#' + $scope.key+' li:nth-child(' + currentCount + ')').addClass('dot-red');

            }

            $scope.api = 
            {
                    reset: function()
                    {
                        timer.reset();
                    },

                    start: function()
                    { 
                        timer.start();
                    },

                    stop: function()
                    {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                };

        }
    };
});
```

This is how it will be used within ng-repeat

`<js-progress api="api1" key="{{activeUserId}}_{{activeCompanyId}}" />`

Now I want to get a particular instance of directive within ng-repeat and call its public API to start, stop and reset the particular progress bar. How can I do the same?

Comment: yes, get instance and then call start function

Comment: I've added a working example to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

JS

```
// array of progress bars
$scope.progressBars = [{id: 0}, {id: 1}];

// Call the api with the instance index, for example
$scope.progressBars[0].start();
```

Markup

```
<div ng-repeat="progressBar in progressBars track by $index>
    <js-progress api="progressBars[$index]" key="{{activeUserId}}_{{activeCompanyId}}" />
</div>
```

So the point here is that the api attribute is passed a different object per repeat.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2QGil71Ce5YcHKh8w07P?p=preview)

Comment: How do I handle the ordering? The $index is not maintained after reordering. I tried to use api="progressBars[{{activeUserId}}] but it said parse error